# ReferenceError: require is not defined in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, eslint

My index.Js file

```
  var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "Hello Vue.js!",
    kafmessage: "null",
  },
  methods: {
    reverseMessage: function () {
      this.message = this.message.split("").reverse().join("");
    },
    sendkafmessagefunction: function (event) {
      var kaf = require('./producer.js');
      var actualmessage = this.kafmessage;
      alert(actualmessage)
    },
  },
});
```

and my producer.js file

```
var Kafka = require("node-rdkafka");

module.exports = function mykafkafunction(actualevent) {
 
  console.log("workin bic!");
}
```

I get an error that

```
Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: require is not defined" vue
```

How do I get my Node.JS file inside the Vue component??

PS don't mind the noob code..

Comment: Two common reasons for that error message: 1) You are trying to run node.js code in the browser as there is not `require()` built into the browser or 2) You are trying to use `require()` in a module that is specified as an ESM module and was imported with `import` as there is no `require()` in an ESM module.

Comment: You should move `var kaf = require('./producer.js')` to the top of `index.js`